# Run php file through ASP.NET Core / IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-10

I have php/fastCgi setup accordingly to my previous asp.net apps, however, it does not work with ASP.NET CORE, it shows 404/NOT FOUND.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this problem? I have just tried to run a PHP script in an asp.net-core app, and facing the same issue. Thx.

Comment: any solution?!?

Comment: I had to host it on a diff environment unfortunately as i did not find any solution